# Suggestions for production music for audio drama

Tags: music, audio-drama

I'm considering taking advantage of some of the end-of-year/holiday sales to beef up my sound collection. I'm especially interested in good production music, for use for audio drama mostly. I've previewed a few of the Sound Ideas collections which seem more targeted at commercials and spots ("The Mix", especially).

Do you have any recommendations for good general-purpose collections of music for underscoring plays? It's a broad and subjective question, I know, but suggestions on places to look would be most appreciated. The specific need is for a project that does a variety of genres of radio  plays, where we don't have the budget for custom music.

Thanks very much

Comment: Contact these guys: http://www.opus1musiclibrary.com/

Answer (score 1):

Logic Studio comes with a lot of program music of different genres.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to keep in mind, although I'm not using Logic at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

"Extreme Music" has some great quality music and a huge range of styles... I use their stuff for radio plays and sketches all the time..

www.extrememusic.com

Answer (score 0):

http://rocksuresoundz.com has production music in a wide range of styles. There is some on there that is free, and the rest of the range starts from $5-95 a track.